# get an element id and then use it in a getElmentByID to trigger a function on click

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function getId(e){
  var xid = e.target.id;
  console.log(xid);
}
```

```html
<form onclick="getId(event)">
    <label for="name" id="I am an Span">Nombre</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="tbx_nombre"> <br>
    <span id="nombre"></span> <br>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

When the user click on a texbox the function gets the id of the element, then the deleteSpan method is call with the splitted id of the textbox which is now the id of the span to be changed to an emply string. 
I get this error *Cannot set property 'onclick' of null at getId*

```
<form onclick="getId(event)">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="tbx_name"><br>
  <span id="name"></span>
   ...MORE INPUTS AND SPAN TAGS...
</form>
```

JS

```
function getId(e){
  var xid = e.target.id;    // => tbx_name
  var spanId = xid.split("_").pop(); // =>name
  document.getElementById(xid).onclick = function(){deleteSpan(spanId)};
}

function deleteSpan(spanId){
  document.getElementById(spanId).innerHTML = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because when you try to set the click handler on the span by ID, you don't currently have the correct ID. It's null, because the click target is currently the form (which doesn't have an ID) instead of the input.

As others mentioned, the click event listener should be attached to the input.

But you also don't need to set a separate click handler within getId--you can just call deleteSpan in the getId function. In fact, if you set it inside another handler like you have, it won't work the first time (unless that's your desired outcome).

```js
function getId(e){
  var xid = e.target.id;    // => tbx_name
  var spanId = xid.split("_").pop(); // =>name
  deleteSpan(spanId);
}
function deleteSpan(spanId){
  document.getElementById(spanId).innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input onclick="getId(event)" type="text" name="name" id="tbx_name"><br>
  <span id="name">Span</span>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, that worked, I do not want to seem stubborn, but it also works when I use the onclick event in the tag form, only that it throws me these errors  Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at deleteSpan 
    at getId 
    at HTMLFormElement.onclick

Answer (score 1):

`onclick` *attribute event handler* should be at `input` instead of `form`

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="tbx_name" onclick="getId(event)"><br>
  <span id="name"></span>
</form>
```

or even better, use `addEventListener` for the inputs which have id format as `tbx_{{value}}`

```
var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[id^='tbx_']");
allInputs.forEach( s => s.addEventListener( "click", e => getId ));
```

You can invoke above code when the `form` has loaded (at `document` *load* or `window` *load*).

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the attribute `onclick` in `input` instead of `form` to get the expected `id`. Otherwise you have to check if the target node is `INPUT` or not:

```js
function getId(e){
  if(e.target.nodeName == 'INPUT'){
    var xid = e.target.id;    // => tbx_name
    var spanId = xid.split("_").pop(); // =>name
    deleteSpan(spanId);
  }
}

function deleteSpan(spanId){
  document.getElementById(spanId).innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<form onclick="getId(event)">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="tbx_name"><br>
  <span id="name">Span</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, in the original code they match, I changed them here so that it could be understood better since they are in another language. if I use getId in the form tag, will return the id of any of the inputs that have clicked, instead of adding onclick event in all the inputs, there are several

Comment: @ThisNameWasTaken, by clicking on `form` how can you pass the `id` of `input` which has been clicked?

Comment: I added a code snippet that shows how I can get the id of the elements inside <form> when I click on them

Comment: @ThisNameWasTaken, do you want the `onclick` event to be in the `input` element?